# How do you keep track of a global variable in python

Tags: python

I want to keep track of the variable `TOTAL_TRI`.  `TOTAL_TRI` contains the number of correctly answered questions from the game.  I need to save that value and pass it to the function `statistics` when `statistics` is called.  Essentially, the player will play the game `py_game`, `TOTAL_TRI` will hold the number of questions they got right, and when the player calls the function `statistics`, it will display the number of questions they got right?  I've been toying with this for a while with no significant progress.  Any ideas?

P.S.
The other games in the menu are not yet implemented, but they'll do the same play-save correct number of questions-and let the player call to `statistics` kind of thing.

```
import random
from random import choice
from random import randint
#py_game------------------------------------------------------------------------
def py_game():
    for k in range (1,3):
        print('\nPractice Problem', k, 'of 2')
        min_pyramid_size = 3
        max_pyramid_size = 5
        total_chars = 0
        num_rows = random.randint(min_pyramid_size, max_pyramid_size)
        for i in range(num_rows):
            x = ''.join(str(random.choice('*%')) for j in range(2*i+1))
            print(' ' * (num_rows - i) + x)
            total_chars = total_chars + x.count('%')
        try:
            user_answer = int(input('Enter the number of % characters' + \
                                    ' in the pyramid: '))
        except:
                user_answer = print()
        if user_answer == total_chars:
            print('You are correct!')
        else:
            print("Sorry that's not the correct answer")
    points = 0
    for k in range (1,11):
        print('\nProblem', k, 'of 10')
        min_pyramid_size = 3
        max_pyramid_size = 5
        total_chars = 0
        num_rows = random.randint(min_pyramid_size, max_pyramid_size)
        for i in range(num_rows):
            x = ''.join(str(random.choice('*%')) for j in range(2*i+1))
            print(' ' * (num_rows - i) + x)
            total_chars = total_chars + x.count('%')
        try:
            user_answer = int(input('Enter the number of % characters' + \
                                    ' in the pyramid: '))
        except:
                user_answer = print()
        if user_answer == total_chars:
            print('You are correct!')
            points +=1
        else:
            print("Sorry that's not the correct answer")
        TOTAL_TRI = points


#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
def statistics(points):

    print('\nPyramid Game---------------------------')
    incorrect = 10 - (points)
    print ('You answered', points, 'questions correctly')
    print ('You answered', incorrect, 'questions incorrectly')



#Main Menu--------------------------------------------------------------------------

def main_menu():
    calculation_game = print("Enter 1 for the game 'Calculation'")
    bin_reader = print("Enter 2 for the game 'Binary Reader'")
    trifacto_game = print("Enter 3 for the game 'Trifacto'")
    statistics = print("Enter 4 to view your statistics")
    display_data = print("Enter 5 to display data")
    save_game = print("Enter 5 to save your progress")
    user_input = int(input('Make your selection: '))
    if user_input == 1:
        calculation()
    if user_input == 2:
        binary_reader()
    if user_input == 3:
        py_game()
    if user_input == 4:
        statistics(TOTAL_TRI)
    if user_input == 5:
        save_game()
    if user_input != 1 or 2 or 3 or 4 or 5:
        print('invalid input')
        print('\n')
        main_menu()



main_menu()
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `globals` is code smell just waiting to happen. Pass your variable as an argument to your function. That's all.